# What is the best way to keep a VGA cable plugged into a laptop

Tags: video, cable

I am looking for the best way to keep a VGA cable plugged into a laptop for an extended period of time. The laptop doesn't have the female end threads like you may see on a video card. Between the VGA port location and my hand size, I knock the cable out often.

I am working on getting a docking station, but not sure when it would be ordered (work-related). I found [an adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BL6B7C), but not sure if it will work.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understsand what the adapter as to do with your question. Can you explain please.

Comment: @criziot I assumed if a can do VGA->USB, I can do that, because generally usb stays in a bit better.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But the link you provided is for a DisplayPort to VGA adapter.

Comment: I was thinking the DP could be used an eSata

Comment: *> The laptop doesn't have the female end threads like you may see on a video card.*   That sounds strange. Are there *holes* beside the connector or is it smooth plastic? If there are holes, then just grab a pair [standoffs](http://images.google.com/images?q=computer+standoffs&sout=1) from a motherboard or case package and screw them in (just make sure that the threading matches… or don’t; either way it should hold the cable).

Comment: from what i've seen, VGA screw nut things (the standoff type parts) are longer and have a finer thread than standoffs.

Comment: "I was thinking the DP could be used an eSata " no no no. totally not the same.

Comment: If you are really comfortable with your drill, some laptops have some free space inside and it may possible for you to add at least one screw nut. But I didn't recommend it if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @Synetech: Sadly, this isn't strange at all when dealing with modern laptops.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, the video-card standoffs are the same as the standoffs on serial and parallel ports, which are almost always 6-32’s. Motherboard standoffs are often M3’s, but I have seen plenty of 6-32’s as well (maybe even ~50%) since the standoff and screw simply have to match each other and have nothing to do with the actual motherboard itself. Video-card standoffs may indeed be a little longer than a typical motherboard standoff though—then again, it’s usually the male end that’s longer more than the female end.

Comment: @Dennis, actually, even if it happens to be *common*, it is still *strange* because leaving them off gains nothing since the actual DE-15F connector sticks out as it is and the standoffs weight and cost next to nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread [VGA Cable - securing to new notebooks](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/hardware/40688-vga-cable-securing-new-notebooks.html) from EduGeek has a couple of good suggestions:

- Wrap a couple of layers of [plastic wrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_wrap) around the male connector. That should cause a tighter fit.
- Use a HD15 M/F adapter (also known as VGA port saver) like this one:

  [image: port saver]

  This will at least protect your port. To make sure it doesn't come out, you could glue it to your laptop. Now you have screw holes for your cable.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. I will see if my company will let me use some double-back tape.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest either self adhesive cable clips (3m makes them with a special, easy to remove adhesive sold under the 'command' brand name) or just use very large binding clips to secure it to the edge of the table.

My first idea was VERY large rubber bands but that will likely get messy, and render your keyboard useless.

Comment: I don't think this would work because I would have to put a clip on my desk about an inch from where I would want to work, and be in the way when I am not using *that* laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm needing to do the same thing. My plan is to use an "L" shaped piece of plastic with a "U" notch that will surround the cable and prevent the VGA from disconnecting.

Here is a mock up I'm using to construct it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to bend the metal casing a little to cause some resistance and it should hold. Other than that try a tighter VGA cable.